# Textbox Onclick = clear value , on exit from textbox set the default value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this in the

```
<asp:TextBox ID="svv" OnClick="this.value=''" runat="server">Hello...</asp:TextBox>

OnClick="this.value=''" // On mouse click in textbox it will deleted the text.
```

How can I set something like

`Unclick"this.defautlvalue"; // something like this.`

So, when I click the control it will clear the value, if I exit from the control (for example, clicking another textbox) it will return the default value of the textbox.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `onBlur`:

`<input type="text" id="fname" onblur="upperCase()">`

This will call `upperCase()` when the user leaves the box.

Answer (score 3):

Specifically with C# .NET WebForms you have a few options.

You can go completely front-end with [jquery](http://www.jquery.com) by doing something like this:

```
 $('selector').blur(function() {
         // Make sure you do some validation so it doesn't clear everytime
         $('selector').val('My Default Text');
    });
```

- Or, if you are using the [AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx), you can simply use The textbox Watermark Control, which will do exactly what you are talking about just by setting a few properties.
- You can also go straight javascript like @m.edmondson explain in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach to the client-side `onblur` event which is called when the focus of your control changes.

Answer (score 0):

Also worth storing the default value in an attribute on the input so you can refer to it in blur event. Believe in ASP.NET web forms you've got to add that attribute in the code-behind though.